# Expected Value of Exponential

Tags: probability, logarithms, normal-distribution, exponential-function, expectation

I want to calculate 
$\log E[\exp(-\sqrt{d} S \epsilon)]$,
where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ and everything else is deterministic. The result should be
$\frac{d}{2}||S||^2$ but why?

Comment: what is $S$ and $\|\cdot\|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** for $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ and $Y:=e^X$, then $Y$ is lognormal distributed with mean $E[Y]=e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$. If you don't know this result, it would be a good exercise.

Comment: Then I get $E[\exp(-\sqrt{d}S\epsilon)]=exp(-\sqrt{d}S+dS^2/2)$ and taking logarithm $-\sqrt{d}S+\frac{dS^2}{2}\neq\frac{d}{2}||S||^2$ right??

Comment: @brikks If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then for a deterministic parameter $c\in\mathbb{R}$ what is the distribution of $cX$? What is $S$ in your case and $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: $cX\sim N(c,c^2)$ ? Because $E[cX]=cE[X]$ and $Var(cX)=c^2 Var(X)$

Comment: @brikks and $E[\epsilon]=0$ so......? Again, what is $S$ and $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: $S$ is a deterministic function, but I am not sure about $||\cdot||$. I suppose it is the absolute value though.

Comment: I was blind. Thanks @user8 for opening my eyes.